# Malformed Line 2 the list of sources can not be read error Linux mint 17.2 Rafaela

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Trying to run `sudo apt-get update` and I get the following error

> Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable.list (type)
>   E: The list of sources could not be read.'

I'm trying to update so I can continue on with getting a lemp stack server running.

Answer (score 0):

---

Suggest : Delete the corrupt repo "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/**nginx-stable.list**"

( If you later on want an updated {bleeding edge 'nginx'}, you can install the updated repo from https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/ )

---

Comment: I go into the directory where the repos are located and manually erase them?

Answer (score 0):

open the file 'nginx-stable.list' with command  '**sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable.list**' and comment the line 2 with starting '#'. 
Then run update command.